# Segmentation Fault When run through menu

Tags: c++

To preface this, I am new to programming.  I am writing a simple shopping list program and I have a do-while loop menu driven program.  When selecting 1 it prompts the user to enter 4 pieces of data that I then send to my Item Class constructor to initiate the values.  Then I add the Item to the List Class array and then it takes you back to the menu.  When selecting 3 from the menu it is supposed to display the list but for some reason I get a segmentation fault.  I have been working on this for 2 days straight now and cannot figure it out (neither could my TA).  I hard coded data into my functions to see if they are working properly and I haven't had any issue with displaying the list, adding Items, or removing Items.  The only problem occurs when I try to use the functions in my menu. Please Help!!!

**Main Function:**

```
int main()
{
/*List sl1;

Item Item1("apple", "unit", 3, 2.00);
Item Item2("grapes", "Pounds", 4, 5.00);
Item Item3("banana", "unit", 6, 2.00);
Item Item4("pears", "ounces", 5, 1.00);

sl1.addItem(&Item1);
sl1.addItem(&Item2);
sl1.addItem(&Item3);
sl1.addItem(&Item4);

sl1.removeItem("banana");
sl1.removeItem("grapes");
sl1.removeItem("pears");

cout << "Total Price: " << sl1.totalPrice() << endl;

sl1.displayList();
*/
int menuChoice;
List sl;
        do
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "1. Add Item to Shopping List" << endl;
            cout << "2. Remove Item from Shopping List" << endl;
            cout << "3. Display Shopping List" << endl;
            cout << "4. Quit" << endl << endl;

            cout << "Please Select 1-4: ";
            cin >> menuChoice;

            if (menuChoice == 1)
            {
                string name;
                string units;
                int quantity;
                double cost;

                cout << endl;
                cout << "Enter Item Name: " << endl;
                cin.ignore(256, '\n');
                getline(cin, name);

                cout << "Enter Item Units (eg. Ounces, Cans): " << endl;
                getline(cin, units);

                cout << "Enter Number of Units Needed: " << endl;
                cin >> quantity;

                cout << "Enter Cost of Item Per Unit: " << endl;
                cin >> cost;

                Item Item1(name, units, quantity, cost);

                sl.addItem(&Item1);

                //sl.displayList();

            }

            else if (menuChoice == 2)
            {
                string name;

                cout << "Please enter the name of the Item you wish to remove: " << endl;
                getline(cin, name);

                sl.removeItem(name);
            }

            else if (menuChoice == 3)
            {
                sl.displayList();

                cout << "Total Price: " << sl .totalPrice() << endl << endl;
            }
        } while (menuChoice != 4);

return 0;
```

}

List Class:

```
List::List()
{
arrayEnd = 0;
for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++)
{
    shoppingList[count] = NULL;
}
}

void List::addItem(Item* inputItem)
{
shoppingList[arrayEnd] = inputItem;
arrayEnd++;
}

void List::removeItem(string itemName)
{
int removedItem = 0;

for (int count = 0; count < arrayEnd; count++)
{
    if (itemName == shoppingList[count]->getItemName())
    {
        shoppingList[count] = NULL;

        removedItem = count;
    }
}

for (int count = 0; count < arrayEnd; count++)
{
    if (count > removedItem)
    {
        shoppingList[count - 1] = shoppingList[count];
        shoppingList[count] = NULL;

        arrayEnd = arrayEnd - 1;
    }
}
}

double List::totalPrice()
{
double totalPrice = 0.0;

if (shoppingList[0] == NULL)
{
    cout << "There are no items in the list" << endl;
}
else 
{
    for (int count = 0; count < arrayEnd; count++)
    {
        totalPrice += shoppingList[count]->getUnitPrice() * shoppingList[count]->getNumberToBuy();
    }
}

return totalPrice;
}

void List::displayList()
{
if (shoppingList[0] == NULL)
{
    cout << "There are no items in the list" << endl;
}
else
{
    for (int count = 0; count < arrayEnd; count++)
    {
        cout << "Item: " << shoppingList[count]->getItemName() << endl;
        cout << "Units: " << shoppingList[count]->getItemUnit() << endl;
        cout << "Quantity: " << shoppingList[count]->getNumberToBuy() << endl;
        cout << "Subtotal: " << shoppingList[count]->getUnitPrice()*shoppingList[count]->getNumberToBuy() << endl << endl;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `sl.addItem(&Item1);`  You are storing pointers to a local variable.  When that variable goes out of scope, that pointer is no longer valid.  Why are you using pointers anyway?  Why not just store objects?

Comment: `I have been working on this for 2 days straight now and cannot figure it out (neither could my TA)`  -- That's real sad that persons on SO can spot the issue within minutes, if not seconds, and you have a TA that can't spot the problem in 2 days.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Very well said!

Comment: Thank you, any suggestions on how to make this menu work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
Item Item1(name, units, quantity, cost);
sl.addItem(&Item1);
```

`Item1` is inside an `if` block, so it will be destructed at the exit from the block. You are therefore adding a pointer to an object that ceases to exist, and bam, seg fault. Technically, you're left with what's called a *dangling pointer*. It's a very dangerous beast.

PS: I would change my TA if I'd be you, as this is some common C++ mistake that decent C++ users should be aware of.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any suggestions on where I need to create the Item object and where to call addItem so that it doesn't delete it?

Comment: @EvanMace If you insist on using pointers, you should probably create the object dynamically, via `new`, like `sl.addItem(new Item{name, unites, quantity, cost});` so it doesn't get destroyed. But your current design is a bit weird, as the list doesn't manage the pointers, so it's your responsibility to `delete` them. So I will suggest to either make the list manage the pointers, i.e. at removal do `delete shoppingList[count];` just before `shoppingList[count] = NULL;` in `List::removeItem`.

Comment: @EvanMace Think more if you really need a list of pointers. It's probably better to store copy of the elements, instead of pointers. A final alternative is to use a list of [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)s. Those are "smart pointers" and manage their resource automatically.

Comment: Thank You! That worked. The assignment forces me to use pointers and arrays, normally I would have used vectors for this assignment but thems the rules.

Comment: @EvanMace You're welcome. Make sure you [read about dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) and how to avoid them. What you bumped into is a pretty common scenario.

Comment: Do I have to use delete in conjunction with the new function cause now my program wont compile after testing it one time?

Comment: You need to `delete` only when removing elements, not after `new`, as otherwise you are left again with dangling pointers. What do you mean "won't compile after testing it one time?" Didn't the program compile before?

Comment: Yes I don't know what happened, I added the line with the new bit, ran the program added two items displayed the list and then exited the program. The tried to run it again and it fails to compile and it wont even send back any lines or error msgs like it usually does if it fails to compile

Comment: @EvanMace What errors are you getting? Try to compile in a command line, or re-create the project in an IDE. If it worked once, it should work again.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio to run it, it ran the first time I tried it and now won't compile didnt do anything in between, and its not sending back any errors it just says failed

Comment: @EvanMace I have no idea what's wrong. Try to create a new project from scratch.

Comment: This time it threw back this error: LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:\Users\Evan\Documents\Oregon State University\CS 162\Module 1\Assignment 1\Assignment 1 Main\Debug\Assignment 1 Main.exe for writing
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @EvanMace It's something wrong with the project folder. You are getting a linker error, not a compiler error, so the code is valid. Create a new project, and make absolutely sure you have write permissions in it.

Comment: Alright I created a new project from scratch and it seems to be alright now. Thank You!!